# Excel Macros with Parameters CountIfS

Tags: excel, vba, parameters, worksheet-function

I am writing a program which searches a spreadsheet full of Olympic Boxing data. Using a combobox, the user selects a country, and a weight class, and upon hitting the Go! button, the program calls a macro in the Excel Spreadsheet which looks like this:

```
Sub paramedals(class As String, country As String)

  MsgBox " Counting by weight class " & class & " and country " & country
  Range("I73").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=COUNTIFS(C[-7], class,C[-6],country,C[-4], ""Gold"")"

End Sub
```

I put in the msgbox command to make sure it was reading the parameters correctly - and it is. The problem is that, rather than setting the formula's parameters to the given strings, it is literally setting the formula to COUNTIFS(B:B, class, etc. .).

Like I said before, I know for a fact that the correct strings are being sent to the macro, because of the msgbox, it displays correctly. Can you just not use parameters for COUNTIFS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate out the string part of the formula from the variables

```
Range("I73").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=COUNTIFS(C[-7]," & class & ",C[-6]," & country & ",C[-4], ""Gold"")"
```

**Edit:**

Both of these work, one is R1C1 and the other is a standard formula

```
Range("I73").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=COUNTIFS(C[-7],""=" & class & """,C[-6],""=" & country & """,C[-4],""=Gold"")"

Range("I73").Formula =  _ 
"=COUNTIFS(B:B,""=" & class & """,C:C,""=" & country & """,E:E,""=Gold"")"
```

A good tip is to build the statement using debug.print or msgbox first and then you can see how it looks when going into a cell.

Comment: Thanks, that caused it to accept the strings correctly. However, it is still not counting the occurences of the strings. 

I notice that in the formula after "running" the macro the class and country strings are not surrounded by quotes, while Gold is. I suppose this makes a serious difference?

I've tried this, something crazy, 

"=COUNTIFS(C[-7]," & """ & class  &""" & ",C[-6]," & """& country & """ & ",C[-4], ""Gold"")"


Hoping that the " surrounded by the other two "'s would be taken as a string and would force "'s around the class and country parameters. It didn't work and I'm out of spa

Comment: This should work (untested): "=COUNTIFS(C[-7],""" & class & """,C[-6],""" & country & """,C[-4], ""Gold"")"   . If you want to do quotes by themselves you should do """" four of them in a row.

Comment: @Jon49 Your syntax works but COUNTIFS requires formula syntax to be =COUNTIFS(Range1,"=Value1",Range2,"=Value2") etc and not=COUNTIFS(Range1,Value1,Range2,Value2)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could replace

```
  Range("I73").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=COUNTIFS(C[-7], class,C[-6],country,C[-4], ""Gold"")"
```

By

```
  Range("I73").Value = application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(<your formula>)
```

Of course, it only works if you can show only the value instead of the formula.